# Should redirections to other questions / answers be comments or answers ?

Tags: support, comments, answers

A part of the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906/ubuntu-and-vlc-make-default-and-hue/913#913) to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/906/270) is, in my opinion, answering another "new" [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/5145/270). I wanted to redirect the person asking the "new" question to the existing answer and posted it as an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5145/why-do-my-avi-files-display-with-funky-colors/5156#5156).

Should it be a comment instead ?

This is related to the discussion [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/268/270). However, this also involves the the "new" question having an accepted answer, relevance & applicability of the answer in this context etc .

Answer (score 3):

Comment or if similar enough vote to close as an exact duplicate (it will post a comment for you).

You wouldn't be adding anything, so it only needs a comment. If you want to reference another post that isn't an exact duplicate but the same answer sort of applies, you can build off the previous answer and tailor it to the question... But don't post duplicate answers for the sake of posting something.

As we go on and more and people ask questions without searching, there are going to be more clashes. It's important we get this right sooner than later or we'll end up with a really messy database of questions and a large clean-up job.